# Hide td if data-id is in array

Tags: jquery, html

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td class="rb-o" data-id="1">a</td>
        <td class="rb-o" data-id="2">b</td>
        <td class="rb-o" data-id="3">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="rb-o" data-id="4"></td>
        <td class="rb-o" data-id="5"></td>
        <td class="rb-o" data-id="6"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

I want to hide the entire `<td>` but only if all its `<data-id>` are in the array list. The table is dynamically generated.

My jQuery:

```
myarray =["2", "4", "5"] ;

$('.rb-o').each(function(index) {
    if (myarray[index]) {
        $(this).attr('data-id', myarray[index]).show();
    }
    else{
        $(this).attr('data-id', myarray[index]).hide();
    }
```

Not working properly.

Answer (score 6):

Try to create a attribute filter using the values in the array and use it to filter the `td`s

```
myarray = ["2", "4", "5"];
$('.rb-o').filter($.map(myarray, function (val) {
    return '[data-id="' + val + '"]'
}).join()).hide()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hb436/)

Answer (score 3):

Make your selection and show the matches. Filter the selection returning only those with `data-id` that exists in your array. Hide the remaining matches.

```
var myarray = [2, 4, 5];

$('.rb-o').show().filter(function(){
    return $.inArray($(this).data('id'), myarray) !== -1
}).hide()
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yS9rP/3/)

If the array values must be strings, you will need to convert the value returned from `.data()` to a string withing `$.inArray()`:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yS9rP/2/)

Comment: you may want to check whether the index is gt 0 instead of returning the index

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `$.inArray()` in Jquery,

```
$('.rb-o').each(function(){
 if($.inArray($(this).data('id'), myarray) > -1){
   $(this).hide()
 }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hb436/3/)